# Would it stay or would it go now?

Tags: support, content

I've been trying to teach myself TDD over the last couple of months, if I put up a whole class and test fixture on SO and asked for people's feedback does this just simply overstep the line of 'Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion.' or would it be tollerable if marked as a community wiki?

Comment: Short answer: No (as in, not tolerable)

Comment: Sounds like too much information.

Comment: People, stop making titles sounding like songs. Won't be able to get that one out of my head for the rest of the evening.

Comment: @Gnoupi: Does that mean I shouldn't ask a question about being addicted to SO and title it "Never gonna give you up"?

Comment: @gnovices - aaaaand now this one is stuck. Thank you, really.

Comment: @Gnoupi: Oops, I did it again.

Comment: @pana - works only with good songs.

Comment: @Gnoupi :) lucky for you I think that one back fired on me actually

Comment: just tell us what you want, what you really really want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this would overstep the line, because you're asking for general feedback.  There's no single objective answer or set of correct answers to that, so it would fail the subjective and not-a-discussion tests.  In your case, Community Wiki is irrelevant; it's designed to allow more people to contribute, not make discussion questions okay.

You get points for coming to meta and asking about what the right thing to do is, though.  We like you.  You can stay.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm marking this as the answer because if I write, "Community Wiki" is irrelevant; it's designed to allow more people to contribute not make discussion questions okay' on my bathroom mirror it will stop me from being tempted to slip in a 'discussion' question in future.

Comment: I don't like him! Burn him! Burn him! :P

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow works best for specific questions, not for a code review. If you narrow down your question, and phrase it in a way that would be helpful to someone else in the future, you'll have much better luck.

Comment: I completely agree with Jon. Also, remember that question/post length is proportional to view and response counts.

Answer (score 1):

There's two questions here, really.  One is if it's likely to be closed, and I think that likely.  Another is what sort of answers you'd get if the question weren't closed, and I don't think you'd get good ones.  Doing an actual code review would be too much like work for me.  You're much better off with specific questions.